# She will leave them(,) as her mother left her. - comma or not?

Tags: restrictive-clauses, non-restrictive

**Example 1**

> She will leave them as her mother left her.

**Example 2**

> She will leave them, as her mother left her.

When "as" is used to mean "in the same way," do we need to add a comma before "as"?

Does that depend on whether it is restrictive?

I did some research, but I still don't understand the difference.

Comment: The version without a comma could mean 'in the same condition as she was in when her mother left her'.